# Azure Data Explorer write query result to cosmo db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-explorer

I have a azure data-explor that queries some syslogs coming-in, filters and aggregate them. The output of this query is store on my local computer in a csv file. So every time a run my Python SDK, it runs a query and saves the output in a csv file.

What I am looking for, is to push that result of the query to a cosmosdb.

Looking into azure GitHub azure-sdk-for-python, I found a library that can achieve this result with this code.

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
import os

url = os.environ['ACCOUNT_URI']
key = os.environ['ACCOUNT_KEY']
client = CosmosClient(url, credential=key)
database_name = 'testDatabase'
database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
container_name = 'products'
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)

for i in range(1, 10):
    container.upsert_item({
            'id': 'item{0}'.format(i),
            'productName': 'Widget',
            'productModel': 'Model {0}'.format(i)
        }
    )
```

But I am a bit confused because they mention `container`.

I was wondering if there is a way that I can push my query result to a database or table using Python SDK.

Thank you so much for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cosmos DB terminology, `Container` is equivalent to a `Table` as Container holds the data like Table. If you're coming from a relational database world, here's the mapping (kind of):

```
Database Server --> Cosmos DB Account

Database --> Database

Table --> Container
```